# how to update all documents after aggregation mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections **A** and **B** and I have a reference of a field in other collection **B** so aggregating the two results in:

`[{"name":"Adam","Average-Count":"20.22","price":"24","_id":2}, ...]`

The documents in collection A is:

`[{"name":"Adam","Average-Count":"0","Last-Name":"Smith","_id":2},....]`

I want to update all the default values of average count field in collection A to correct value that i have got after aggregation 
Is their a way to update all the documents in a single query or if we can update the documents in the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please explain the problem in detail so we can understand it, be consistent with your naming e.g. of collections and use the formatting options which are available.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: if you can keep document structure during aggregation, use $our stage to override your collection. Warning, can be used once only, try with sample collection before...

Comment: $out would update the existing collection? if i specify the same name

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to update all the documents in a single query or if we can update the documents in the aggregation pipeline?

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the update command can use an aggregation pipeline for the update. The pipeline can consist of the following stages at the moment: [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set), [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset), and [$replaceWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith).

Since your question involves joining collections first in the pipeline with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage, as this is not currently a supported stage, you could either:

- Modify the [document data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) to combine the collection, and use the update with aggregation pipeline.
- Keep the data model, and use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) aggregation stage

`$merge` can incorporate results (insert new documents, merge documents, replace documents, keep existing documents, fail the operation, process documents with a custom update pipeline) into an **existing** collection. For example:

```
{ "$merge": { 
     into: "A", 
     on: "_id", 
     whenMatched: "replace", 
     whenNotMatched: "insert" 
}}
```